# Jetpack Compose TextField text underline stays when disabled

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I have a `TextField` for which I want to programmatically controll whether it's enabled.
When I disable the TextField, I want the focus to be cleared and the keyboard to be hidden.
The following is a minimum example of the behavior I want:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Content() {
  // styling omitted
  Column {
    var enabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    val (text, setText) = remember { mutableStateOf("Hello World") }
    TextField(text, setText, enabled = enabled)
  
    Button(onClick = { enabled = !enabled }) { Text(if (enabled) "disable" else "enable") }
  }
}
```

**My Problem** is that text **decorations** placed by the keyboard (e.g. underlining the current word) ***stay* when** the TextField is **disabled**. How can I fix that? Note that I don't just want to remove the text decorations while the TextField is focussed (I believe this could be achieved by setting the keyboard style to password).

[image: Current word is underlined while typing]

Current Word is underlined while typing - that's ok

[image: Underlining stays when disabled]

Text underline stays when text field is disabled and keyboard is removed - that's not ok